# Technical name of commands like Alt+F4, Ctrl+Alt+DEL, Alt+Tab

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, terminology

I want to learn about those commands in Windows Explorer, and I was wondering if there is a technical name for them, so I can look up for some documentation, as I couldn't find any.

Thanks!

Comment: Also the 'technical name' for 'technical name' is sometimes 'terminology' (term for short). I've added it as a tag. You can find many interesting things, by knowing this word, although not always.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Those are "Keyboard shortcuts for Windows". There is a [Microsoft Knowledge Base article on keyboard shortcuts](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/126449) that lists most of them and explains what they do.

Comment: No matter how experienced you are, you can always learn something new. I never knew **ALT** + **ENTER** opened the properties dialog.

Comment: At one time i did know a lot of these but if you don't use them regularly you keep forgetting them.